# Perl search for a content in file and take out value using regex

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a set of log files where I want to search for a word called `Sum` in each file and take the respective sum value out which is next to `Sum` keyword in the file.

Instead of doing file read operation I am using `Tie::File` to have the content of file in array and thinking to take out whatever value I needed.

Here is my code:

```
...
my $logpath = "C:/Users/Vinod/Perl/LOG/";

opendir(DIR, $logpath);
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    next unless (-f "$logpath/$file");
    next unless ($file =~ m/\.log$/);

    my @lines;
    print "$file\n";

    tie @lines, 'Tie::File', $file, mode => O_RDWR;

    for (@lines) {
        print $_ if($_ =~ m/Sum/);
    }
    untie @lines;
}
closedir(DIR);
```

Here is what I am trying to extract from my log file:
test_log_file.log

```
....
....
=
> Sum: 10 PC's, 5 UPS's
End...
```

From the above `test_log_file.log` I want to take out value `10`.

But the line `print $_ if($_ =~ m/Sum/);` is printing entire file content. No idea how I can take out the line which contains `Sum` and `PC` keywords. So that I can have value `10` using regex.

I can able to take out Sum value using below command:
`$sum = qx/more $file | grep -i 'Sum' | grep 'PC' | awk -F " " '{print \$3}'/;`

But wanted to resolve this using Perl script itself.

Answer (score 2):

Read line by line. Capture the number and output only the captured part:

```
while (<>) { say $1 if /Sum: ([0-9]+)/ }
```

Comment: Reading line by line is one solution I understand. But would it be _faster_ compare using linux commands which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try and benchmark. But using just one tool that does everything is usually faster than switching between different tools.